# What does Ng Lieu Cho really say at the end of S04E11?

Tags: dialogue, translation, mad-about-you

At the end of *Mad About You* season 4 episode 10 ("Get Back"), Paul Buchman (Paul Reiser) "translates" for the dissident poet Ng Lieu Cho (Jim Lau), because he fails to pick up Professor Gittleson (Leland Orser).  What does Ng Lieu Cho really say?